# Improving an algorithm for detecting fish in a canal

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I have many hours of video captured by an infrared camera placed by marine biologists in a canal. Their research goal is to count herring that swim past the camera. It is too time consuming to watch each video, so they'd like to employ some computer vision to help them filter out the frames that do not contain fish. They can tolerate some false positives and false negatives, and we do not have sufficient tagged training data yet, so we cannot use a more sophisticated machine learning approach at this point.

I am using a process that looks like this for each frame:

1. Load the frame from the video

[image: Frame from video]

2. Apply a Gaussian (or median blur)

[image: Blurred frame]

3. Subtract the background using the BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 class

[image: Frame minus background]

4. Apply a brightness threshold — the fish tend to reflect the sunlight, or an infrared light that is turned on at night — and dilate

[image: Image after threshold applied]

5. Compute the total area of all of the contours in the image
6. If this area is greater than a certain percentage of the frame, the frame may contain fish. Extract the frame.

To find optimal parameters for these operations, such as the blur algorithm and its kernel size, the brightness threshold, etc., I've taken a manually tagged video and run many versions of the detector algorithm using an evolutionary algorithm to guide me to optimal parameters.

However, even the best parameter set I can find still creates many false negatives (about 2/3rds of the fish are not detected) and false positives (about 80% of the detected frames in fact contain no fish).

I'm looking for ways that I might be able to improve the algorithm. I don't know specifically what direction to look in, but here are two ideas:

- Can I identify the fish by the ellipse of their contour and the angle (they tend to be horizontal, or at an upward or downward angle, but not vertical or head-on)?
- Should I do something to normalize the lighting conditions so that the same brightness threshold works whether day or night?

(I'm a novice when it comes to OpenCV, so examples are very appreciated.)

Comment: Look for Gaussian mixture models to model the background over time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The *BackgroundSubtractorMOG2* that OP is using is already based on Mixture Of Gaussians, or was there some literature or article you were suggesting?

Comment: Can you maybe share some video footage - maybe via Dropbox or Google Drive or similar as you can't share video directly on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mark: I wasn’t aware of that. That output doesn’t look right though.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Agreed... maybe OP could share some code too please.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're in the correct direction. Your camera is fixed so it will be easy to extract the fish image. 
But you're lacking a good tool to accelerate the process. believe me, coding will cost you a lot of time.

Personally, in the past i choose few data first. Then i use [bgslibrary](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary) to check which background subtraction method work for my data first. Then i code the program by hand again to run for the entire data. The GUI is very easy to use and the library is awesome.

[GUI video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UbERwuQ0OU)

Hope this will help you.